# Where is the Cocoa Pods Podfile kept?

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

I need to add to a Cocoa Pods Podfile to install SwiftLint, but install docs and forums 'gloss' over the detail of where it's located.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and in the root of your project directory run...

```
pod init
```

That will create the pod file and all the other parts of the project that are needed.

If you can’t do that... the pod file lives in the root directory of your project.